# Trouble Uploading Large Files to OneDrive via Microsoft Graph API (Status Code 400)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to upload large files (greater than 150MB) to OneDrive using the Microsoft Graph API. The upload process works seamlessly for smaller files, but for larger files, it creates temporary storage and then fails with a status code 400.

I'm using Node.js and Axios to handle the upload process. The upload session is being successfully created, and I'm uploading the file in chunks using the 'Content-Range' header. However, when the file size exceeds 150MB, the upload consistently fails after some time.

I have ensured that the access token and file paths are correct, and the issue seems to be related to the file size or upload process.

Has anyone else encountered a similar problem when uploading large files to OneDrive using the Microsoft Graph API? I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to address this issue and ensure successful uploads for larger files.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const axios = require('axios');

const accessTokenFilePath = './access_token.json'

const accessTokenData = fs.readFileSync(accessTokenFilePath, 'utf8');
const { access_token: accessToken } = JSON.parse(accessTokenData);

const filePath = './sun-europe-trees-woods-yellow-above-natural-2023-02-27-20-26-28-utc.mp4';

const uploadFileToOneDrive = async (filePath, accessToken) => {
    let uploadUrlerror = null;
    try {
        const fileStats = fs.statSync(filePath);
        const fileSize = fileStats.size;

        // Create upload session
        const url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/envato';
        const fileName = filePath.split('/').pop();
        const uploadSessionResponse = await axios.post(`${url}/${fileName}:/createUploadSession`, null, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
            }
        });

        const uploadUrl = uploadSessionResponse.data.uploadUrl;
        uploadUrlerror = uploadUrl;

        // Upload file in chunks
        const chunkSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5MB chunk size
        let offset = 0;

        while (offset < fileSize) {
            const chunk = fs.readFileSync(filePath, {
                encoding: null,
                start: offset,
                end: offset + chunkSize - 1
            });

            const range = `bytes ${offset}-${offset + chunk.length - 1}/${fileSize}`;
            console.log(`Uploading range ${range}...`);

            await axios.put(uploadUrl, chunk, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
                    'Content-Length': chunk.length,
                    'Content-Range': range
                }
            });

            offset += chunk.length;
        }

        console.log('File uploaded successfully');
        return true;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error uploading file to OneDrive:', error.message);
        return false;
    }
};
```